# How to make a QTabWidget to dockable

Tags: python, pyqt4, docking, qtabwidget

My tab widget of type QTabWidget which contains many tab pages renders with following default options set:

```
self._tabOptions = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
self._tabOptions.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
self._tabOptions.setDocumentMode(False)
self._tabOptions.setTabsClosable(False)
self._tabOptions.setMovable(False)
```

It works fine. What I need is to make this QTabWidget dockable so as for user to freely interact with.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [dock widget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html) and [add it](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#addDockWidget) to the main window; then [add](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#setWidget) the tab widget to the dock widget:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.dock = QtGui.QDockWidget('Tab Options', self)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dock)
        self.dock.setWidget(self._tabOptions)
```